# What's the usual sigma-algebra on $\mathbb R^\infty$?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, metric-spaces

I'm reading some lecture notes about time series where the author mentions measurable functions from $\mathbb R^\infty$ to $\mathbb R$. I was never introduced to $\mathbb R^\infty$, so I have a few questions:

> 1. What's the standard meaning of $\mathbb R^\infty$ ? Is it the space of sequences of real numbers ($\mathbb R^{\mathbb N})$?
> 2. What's the usual sigma-algebra on $\mathbb R^\infty$ ? I guess it is the Borel sigma-algebra, but one needs to specify a metric or a topology in the first place. What's the most natural/common metric/topology used ?

---

Here's the context in which $\mathbb R^\infty$ is used:
Let $(Z_t)_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ be a strictly stationary, ergodic process and $f:\mathbb R^\infty \to \mathbb R^d$ be measurable. Let $Y_t=f(Z_t, Z_{t-1},\ldots)$. Then $(Y_t)_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ is strictly stationary and ergodic.

Comment: Could you include more context from the lecture notes? It would help us give an answer if you showed how $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ was used in these notes or why it was mentioned.

Comment: Traditionally, $\Bbb R^{\infty}$ is the space of sequences if you are not given extra information. Unlike $\Bbb R^n$, $\Bbb R^{\infty}$ is very ambiguous as you could put a lot of very different topologies on it. Presumably you would put the product topology on it since you have no extra qualifying information (usually in this case, you assume product topology). In that case, I think the sigma algebra would be generated by products of open intervals. I'm not sure if the usual construction for the Borel sets goes through or not since you have infinitely many "variables" so to speak.

Comment: @MiloBrandt I've added all the context I got.

Comment: Besides topology, $\mathbb{R}^\infty$ is ambiguous even as a set. In the context of algebraic topology (which can stray somewhat afar from measure theory or analysis), it is the direct limit of the sequence of standard inclusions $\mathbb{R} \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 \hookrightarrow \cdots$, which makes it into the space of eventually zero sequences of real numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ is being used as the space of all maps $\mathbb N\rightarrow\mathbb R$. In categorical terms, the author here wants to use the direct product (in the category of measurable spaces) of one copy of $\mathbb R$ for each natural number - since this is the right way to make the expression $f(Z_t,Z_{t-1},\ldots)$ make sense if $f$ is a measurable map $\mathbb R^{\infty}\rightarrow\mathbb R^d$.

Explicitly, the $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb R^{\infty}$ is the one generated by sets of the form $\{x\in \mathbb R^{\infty}:x_i\in U\}$ where $i\in \mathbb N$ and $U\subseteq \mathbb R$ is open.